# How to handle the authentication token during page load in a PHP application?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, rest, authentication

I am confused a bit about a matter. I have made a restful api in php where the entry point is index.php.

Now the point is when a user 'll login a random generated token 'll be sent to the user and from then for any request(to receive html page or json data) user has to sent the token with the request, else user 'll get a 401,unauthorised response.

Now when user 'll make an ajax call the the token has to be sent via http header; and there is no problem. But my confusion is when a user ask for a html page(e.g. report.html) how 'll the user sent the token to authenticate himself/herself before accessing the page?

Currently my solution is as following;

```
 http://host/app-name/page/token
```

Is it the right way?

For your information login page can be accessed without token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the [Header](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/http-headers-for-dummies--net-8039) of your request.

Basically, the Header is something that will define your request to the server, the location of the request, the device, the browser,...

By sending it that way your server can handle the authentication without having to read your request, the best way of implementing would be to create a function that will be called before any other to check if the token is valid.

I would recommend using [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) for testing your API, it's simple but effective.

There are other way of identification that are deemed safer if you're interested (look [here](https://stormpath.com/blog/secure-your-rest-api-right-way))

I hope that this will help you, have a nice day ;)

Comment: Yup you are exactly right. But can you please give me a idea about page redirecting. Like I am currently in abc.html and now after a button click I want to go to xyz.html. For this particular case how 'll I do the authentication, I mean user is authenticated or not for viewing xyz.html. And I use Postman; its really a good tool. :)

Comment: On the client side you should use cookies: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie
this will allow you to store data on the client side.

Comment: Ok, I stored it in client side(not in cookie but in localstorage) but now how 'll I send that client side stored data(token) to server apart from ajax call.

Comment: The purpose of an api is to make explicit call that will retrieve data, that's it. It appears that you want more of a classic session auth.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that but you need to think more about your needs and if an api is the real answer to them.